# R DataTable Solution To Making Sum Columns

Tags: r, data.table

```
data1=data.frame("group1"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 "group2"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 "var1"=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0),
                 "var2"=c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1),
                 "var3"=c(1,1,4,3,3,1,1,2,4,1,4,4,4,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,1,2,4))


data2=data.frame("group1"=rep(c(rep(1:3,2)),2),
                 "group2"=rep(c(rep(1:2,3))),
                 "var1"=sort(rep(0:1,6)),
                 "svar1" = c(2,2,0,3,3,3,1,2,4,1,1,1),
                 "var2"=sort(rep(0:1,6)),
                 "svar2" = c(rep(NA,12)))
```

I have 'data1' and hope to make 'data2'. What it does is it collapses the actual counts of 'var1' and 'var2' to create 'svar1' and 'svar2' in 'data2'.

to create 'svar1' we sift through all combinations of 'group1' and 'group2' in 'data1' and then just store the sum of all occurances of '0' and '1' which are the response options for 'var1'. I wish to also do this for 'var2' to generate 'svar2'

I also hope for a data.table solution given the big data!! For now we can ignore 'var3'!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data.table based approach with joins. I think, in the result, the supposition is that `var1 = var2` on each row, and `svar1` and `svar2` are the row counts in the original data frame with those combinations.

I'll leave duplicating the `var1` column and filling the `NA`s in with `0`s to you.

```
setDT(data1)

merge(
  data1[, .(svar1 = .N), by = .(group1, group2, var1)],
  data1[, .(svar2 = .N), by = .(group1, group2, var2)],
  by.x = c("group1", "group2", "var1"),
  by.y = c("group1", "group2", "var2"),
  all = TRUE
)
#     group1 group2 var1 svar1 svar2
#  1:      1      1    0     2     1
#  2:      1      1    1     2     3
#  3:      1      2    0     3     2
#  4:      1      2    1     1     2
#  5:      2      1    0     3     3
#  6:      2      1    1     1     1
#  7:      2      2    0     2     3
#  8:      2      2    1     2     1
#  9:      3      1    0    NA     4
# 10:      3      1    1     4    NA
# 11:      3      2    0     3     2
# 12:      3      2    1     1     2
```